# Problem switching GPUs with prime-select (nvidia and intel)

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, intel-graphics, xorg.conf

Im pretty new to Linux and Im triying to get working both my integrated Intel and dedicated Nvidia (1050 Ti) GPUs in my dell XPS 9570, with prime-select program, but Im having troubles.

If I dont touch the xorg.conf generated with `nvidia-xconfig`:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 430.50


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

my intel graphic works great but a I get a black screen with the nvidia one.

If i use this xorg.conf (I took it in nvidia forum):

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "nvidia"
    Inactive       "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "intel"
    Driver     "modesetting"
    BusID      "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option     "AccelMethod" "None"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "intel"
    Device     "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "nvidia"
    BusID      "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    Option     "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "nvidia"
    Device         "nvidia"
    Option     "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option     "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection
```

the nvidia gpu works but the intel one get black screen in booting.

Any ideas to fix this? I purge and reinstal nvidia (as usual pipeline) many times, but the error keeps.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

With this xorg.conf:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "intel"
    Driver         "modesetting"
    BusID          "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
enter code here
```

Im able to boot with both GPUs without black screens but the nvidia one looks death. I mean, `nvidia-smi` does not show any kind of usded memory neither running tasks. Any ideas?